# How to optimize MarkerWithLabel on google maps when having too many markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-markers

I have been developing an application on google chrome, and I've been using the  MarkerWithLabel library, which i believe is written by google developers. I am using a little over 100 markers on the map and it seemed to be pretty smooth until i checked in firefox (and lets not even mention IE). It is pretty damn laggy in FF. Any way to optimize it?

http://jsfiddle.net/zDTNS/2 `Here is a sample in jsfiddle`

To clarify, having 200 regular markers works fine. The problem shows up when using MarkerWithLabel

Comment: In v3 100 markers should be reasonable quick, it is thousands of markers where performance issues occur.  I have seen [reports of a slow down in adding markers in later releases](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6140), perhaps try 3.13.

Comment: [fiddle using 3.13](http://jsfiddle.net/FL3d7/2/)

Comment: That does not seem to be an issue with me. The links you have perform the same on my machine. Chrome is smooth, Firefox lags on both.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? I get no issues on my machine but again this is dependent largely on the clients set-up and not the server side application. This is why maps applications are so difficult to optimize, and why I suggested clustering (though obviously this isn't a viable solution for you).

Comment: I have issues with your example: 1) no infowindow opens if I click on the markers or the labels 2) regarding the text you have there *"The two markers shown here"*... there are much more than two 3) where do you see the page being slow in FF - i.e. what do you mean by *"It is pretty damn laggy in FF"*?

Comment: @Tomas 1) I dont need any infowindows. 2)updated the text, sorry about that. 3)in firefox when i drag or zoom the map, it is a very choppy experience. maybe you have a powerful machine, so try to increase the loop to 500

Comment: My experience with FF and this code: it is really different than Chrome, IE and Safari. But what I see is the same if I have 100, 1 or none MarkerWithLabel: when I drag map left and right, it is moving in jumps and not smoothly as for example with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 2 weeks researching and trying all sorts of methods, most suggested on here, I arrived to the conclusion that there just is no way to optimize at the moment. For some reason firefox struggles when there are divs on top of the map and keeping them in sync. The performance on the latest firefox was almost the same as IE8.

I found that having a ton of google markers does not cause any lagging, but divs do. What I ended up doing was create a server side function that converts text to png. When initializing the google marker, you make the icon url `TextToImage.aspx?text=Hello&size=13`
Then I set the anchor of the new marker to (15, 15) and that became my new 'label'. I added some click and mouseover listeners to the label marker and voila! Insane improvement to performance.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking the best way to optimize any Google maps application is using a clustering technique. As the application loads more and more markers the client-side rendering over-head will only increase. The addition of labels only compounds the issue.

A number of clustering techniques exist and are simple to implement, I'd suggest starting with this article: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.

*Edit* Leaving above in place in case anyone doesn't have the same spec requirement, but similar issue.

My only other suggestion would be to turn off the labels when above a certain zoom level? This will at least alleviate some of the worst of the rendering issues.

*Edit* After doing a bit of research the library introduced [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/GRciQWYLLeU) has been shown to have far more favorable performance characteristics than markerWithLabel. It relies on a html canvas though so is ie9+.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but unfortunately none of those methods meets the client requirements. I need to show all markers in the viewport for the U.S.

Comment: How many markers are we talking? In my experience things start to slow down at around the 80 mark depending on the browser/machine in use.

Comment: I have about 70~80, but i think MarkerWithLabel doubles that. not sure though.

Comment: correction. after looking at the code, MarkerWithLabel adds divs for each marker.

Comment: Yes sorry you're correct, the labels are individual divs positioned relatively to the parent marker. Disabling these at specific zoom levels may not greatly impact performance unless we're talking about 000's of markers.

Comment: thanks for the alternatives, but i'd rather use markerWithLabel since i have alrady spend a ton of hours implementing that. Also it has events just like the marker it is attached too, which i definitely need. and it works in IE8. I'm just looking for optimization

Comment: If all you need is a label then you should create your own overlay. A good example here: http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html Doing this way, I am able to add up to 500 markers before it starts to slow down with FF. With Chrome, I can add 1000 without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a couple of characters inside a pin, another alternative is:

`https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=${displayCharacters}|${pinColorHex}|${fontColorHex}`

Check [this example](https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|FE6256|000000).