# Google map api marker rendering

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm having an issue when I create a large number of marker labels on the google maps API. I'm using [maplabels](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/docs/reference.html) and they work fine when I just use a few. Once I load a couple hundred they cause the browser to be rendered incorrectly (all white) in chrome. I'm using version 32.0.1700.72. They render fine in Firefox (although it's a little slow) and great in IE. Here's a JSFiddle to show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ATuaK/1/

Once the map becomes idle I add 400 markers and labels:

```
    var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
        text: 'Test'
    });
```

Try browsing in Chrome and moving the map to move off some icons and the issue will fix itself. Any ideas of what could be going on? Am I creating too many canvas elements for chrome to handle?

Here's an image of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: Check [How to optimize MarkerWithLabel on google maps when having too many markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636943/how-to-optimize-markerwithlabel-on-google-maps-when-having-too-many-markers). It is using MarkerWithLabel library, but the conclusion could be the same (great number of div elements).

Comment: "they cause the browser to be rendered incorrectly (all white) in chrome" What do you mean? It's slow, but I see no rendering issue here. Chrome version is 32.0.1700.77. Just tested with 31.x and it was fine too.

Comment: That's strange... I've tested on multiple machines. I added an image so you can see what I'm talking about. Parts of the page just don't render at all.

Comment: Anto, thanks for the comment and link. I'll see if I can play around with odle's solution.

Comment: I ended up generating my labels using HTML5 canvas and a second marker. I created a function to generate a custom text icon url and attached that to the normal google marker. I used BindTo to attach the second marker to the first and set the anchor so it appears below the first like a label. I also added all the markers to a marker manager which allows me to set different zooms for the icon markers and label markers. It seems to be working well! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.